# What is faster: JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am starting to use JavaScript and JQuery. I know JQuery makes programmer's life easier, it allows for save code lines. My question is for simple tasks like:

```
document.getElementById('id').value = "";
$('#id').val('');
```

what is faster?

Thank's

Comment: jquery is javascript

Comment: Take a look here https://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascript-performance-comparison/77

Comment: @Praveen Kumar - That's not a very useful duplicate - doesn't have particularly good answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nearly all plain Javascript functions will be faster than jQuery operations.  This is because jQuery has overhead in creating a jQuery object in order to be more flexible, allow for chaining, support collections, etc...

99.99% of the time, the difference in performance is immaterial and the ability to write code faster in jQuery and use all of its cross browser support is an advantage worth using.

The prudent developer uses advanced tools to make writing code faster and easier and then only when you have a documented performance issue, do you measure where the performance bottleneck is coming from and code around it with faster code (perhaps bypassing jQuery in one or two spots if required).

---

As an example of the speed of writing code using jQuery, it could take a bit of time to write this equivalent in plain Javascript:

```
$(".sections, .dividers").slideDown().animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, 3000, function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Here, since this is all animations done over a period of time, the time to execute the jQuery statement is immaterial.